# JSONArray from MySQL Query using PHP does not work with complicated query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a PHP scirpt which returns  JSONAray from MySQL query. It works with most queries but I need to get result from specific long one.

Here is PHP function script:

```
public function getTopRecipes() {
    $myArray = array();
    if ($result = $this->conn->query("SELECT recipe.`unique_id`, recipe.`title`, recipe.`img_tumbnail_link`, recipe.`add_date`, recipe.`kitchen_type`, recipe.`meal_type`, user.`name`, user.`surname`, COUNT(`like`.`recipe_unique_id_fk`) AS like_count
        FROM `recipe`
        JOIN `like` ON (recipe.`unique_id` = `like`.`recipe_unique_id_fk`)
        JOIN `user` ON (user.`unique_id` = recipe.`user_unique_id_fk`)
        WHERE recipe.`acceptance` = '1' 
        GROUP BY `like`.`recipe_unique_id_fk`
        ORDER BY like_count DESC")) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($myArray);
    }
    $result->close();
}
```

This script returns blank page without any JSON data. However this script runs perfectly when getting result from phpMyAdmin. Here is example:

[image]

I have no idea what's wrong :/ Can you guys help me? Thank you.

Comment: Well, most likely your query fails, why ever. Since you do not do any error detection / handling at all you probably won't realize it fails. I suggest you start b taking a look into your error log file to read what happens.

Comment: Just `print_r` the `$row` inside loop and make sure query returns data.

Comment: I'm assuming that this is using mysqli - should the constant therefore not be: `MYSQLI_ASSOC ` ?

Comment: There are acutally no errors. Response code is 200 which tells it's ok.

Comment: No, the http status 200 does _not_ tell you everything is OK. A failing sql query is not final.

Comment: I changed form `MYSQL_ASSOC` to `MYSQLI_ASSOC` but that didn't help. I am wodnering why this query works in MySQL console in phpMyAdmin and does not in script? Rest of scripts works normally both here and here.

Comment: I did like @Harikrishnan said and used `print_r`. Here are results:http://anton869.linuxpl.eu/android_login_api/toprecipes.php Look like query returns correctresults but there is problrm with json_encode :/

Answer (score 0):

When the query works but your script does not, the problem is in the JSON encoding as mentioned by @anton86993.

Check for any special characters in the results. These could include umlauts, french accents etc.

To confirm this replace the contents of the result with a simple string and run  your code.

Comment: I have only some Polish lletters like ś, ł, ć... I changed hem to s, l, c and script still prints nothing. However if I do print_r($array) after filling array witf `FETCH` I can see that array is filled perfectly fine with correct values.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was with the text encode. If you fetch data from MySQL you always have to remember to set default charset to UTF-8 with **mysqli::set_charset()** function before fetching data. Here is working final code if somebody ever had the same problem.

```
public function getTopRecipes() {
    $myArray = array();
    $this->conn->set_charset("utf8");
    if ($result = $this->conn->query("SELECT recipe.`unique_id`, recipe.`title`, recipe.`img_tumbnail_link`, recipe.`add_date`, recipe.`kitchen_type`, recipe.`meal_type`, user.`name`, user.`surname`, COUNT(`like`.`recipe_unique_id_fk`) AS like_count
        FROM `recipe`
        JOIN `like` ON (recipe.`unique_id` = `like`.`recipe_unique_id_fk`)
        JOIN `user` ON (user.`unique_id` = recipe.`user_unique_id_fk`)
        WHERE recipe.`acceptance` = '1' 
        GROUP BY `like`.`recipe_unique_id_fk`
        ORDER BY like_count DESC")) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($myArray); 
    }
    $result->close();
}
```